# Xcode Autocompletion: Meaning of "+1 more"?

Tags: swift, xcode

What is meant here with "+1 more"?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's indicating that there are more overloads with the same parameter labels. This is a new feature added in Xcode 14.

In this case, it is showing [this overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup/init(_:content:)-9byxn):

```
init<S>(_ label: S, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) where S : StringProtocol
```

and the "+1 more" refers to [this other overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup/init(_:content:)-1h8f8):

```
init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content)
```

You can expand to see all the overloads by selecting that row in the dropdown, and pressing the right arrow key.

Notice that both of them has 2 parameters, the labels for the parameters are both `_:content:`. i.e. the first parameter has no label, and the second parameter has "content" as label.